# Where to put the code for a Google Adwords campaing on Magento 1.9.1?

Tags: google-analytics

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
```

We are running an Adwords campaing and we were given the following code to place into the Magento shopping cart in order to track how successful the campaign is:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics --> 
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-118694738-1"></script> 
<script> 
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; 
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);} 
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-113694994-1'); 
</script>
```

I've tried putting this in the CMS home page,

1. In the "`Porto - Settings Panel`" under Customization `Settings --> Custom Style`
2. Under `GENERAL --) DESIGN --)  HTML HEAD --) Miscellaneous Scripts` but it does not seem to work.

Where is the best place to place this code within Magento?

Comment: Check the answer & give feedback ;)

Answer (score 0):

Search for **checkout/cart.phtml** file (if I've understood your requirements right it should be placed *only* in cart page) in your **app/design/frontend** folder

You'll probably find more than one result, due to Magento theme fallback system https://www.classyllama.com/blog/depth-look-magento-theme-fallback

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
>
> app/design/frontend/XXX/XXX/template/checkout/cart.phtml
>
> etc...

Locate which one is being rendered in your project, and place that Analytics JS code there